# return json result in view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a newsletter text box that renders in a PartialView. This is the get action:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult NewsLetterSidebar()
{
    return PartialView("_NewsLetterSidebar");
}
```

And this is the Razor view:

```
model Blog.Web.UI.ViewModels.NewsLetterViewModel 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_NewsLetterSidebar";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("NewsLetter", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <h3>News Letter</h3>
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(news => news.EmailAddress)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(news => news.EmailAddress)
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Verify">
    </div>
}
```

I want the success message to appear under the verify button in case of valid input. This is my post action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult NewsLetter(NewsLetterViewModel newsLetter)
{
    var newsLetterViewModel = newsLetter.ConvertToNewsLetterModel();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _newsLetterRepository.Add(newsLetterViewModel);
        _newsLetterRepository.Save();
    }
    return Json("Done!");
}
```

How can I show the JSON message under the View?

Comment: Are you going to change the page or simply post the data and stay where you are at?

Comment: no I don't want to change the page , I just wanna to show the success or Unsuccess  message , that all

Comment: You could change the action for POST to return not JSON but the whole page (or partial view, it depends on your views structure) but with "Done!" message rendered. Alternatively you could call POST action via AJAX, get JSON from the controller and render the message in Javascript. Which way do you prefer?

Comment: so first one is simpler and fluent , but how ?? I couldn't find any related sample

Comment: @EricNielsen does the below answers any help for you? I think you should respond to the answers you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but will help you to complete what you want.

```
[HTTPGET]
public JsonResult NewsLetter(NewsLetterViewModel newsLetter)
{
    var newsLetterViewModel = newsLetter.ConvertToNewsLetterModel();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _newsLetterRepository.Add(newsLetterViewModel);
        _newsLetterRepository.Save();
    }
    return Json("Done!", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

replace this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewsLetter", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{}
```

with

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NewsLetter", "Home", new AjaxOptions{ onsuccess:"ShowMessage"}))
    {}
```

JS

```
function ShowMessage(data){
alert(data);
}
```

Comment: thanks , I tested your answer and it works , do you also know how should I show the json result message in View ??

Comment: if you wan to just display the JSON result as is then use this new AjaxOptions{ updateTargetID }. or if you have to build mark up from JSON then in ShowMessage function var d = JSON.Parse(data); d.PropertyName and so on...

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use the first approach from my comment above, you need slightly modify your code. First of all, add `Message` property to your `NewsLetterViewModel`, then change the partial view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NewsLetter", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId = "newsletter-container"}))
{
    <h3>News Letter</h3>
    <span>@Model.Message</span>
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(news => news.EmailAddress)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(news => news.EmailAddress)
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Verify">
    </div>
}
```

Please noеe that your partial view should be wrapped into a html element with `id="newsletter-container"` on your page e.g:

```
<div id="newsletter-container">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_NewsLetterSidebar", new NewsLetterModel());}
</div>
```

Now, a small change in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewsLetter(NewsLetterViewModel newsLetter)
{
    var newsLetterViewModel = newsLetter.ConvertToNewsLetterModel();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _newsLetterRepository.Add(newsLetterViewModel);
        _newsLetterRepository.Save();
            model.Message = "Done!";
    }

    return PartialView("_NewsLetterSidebar", model);
}
```

You also need to add `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` to make it work.